# Which bit is first and when you bit shift, does it actually shift in that direction?

Tags: c++

So.. wrestling with bits and bytes, It occurred to me that if i say "First bit of nth byte", it might not mean what I think it means. So far I have assumed that if I have some data like this:

00000000 00000001 00001000

then the

1. First byte is the leftmost of the groups and has the value of 0
2. First bit is the leftmost of all 0's and has the value of 0
3. Last byte is the rightmost of the groups and has the value of 8
4. Last bit of the second byte is the rightmost of the middle group and has the value of 1

Then I learned that the byte order in a typed collection of bytes is determined by the endianess of the system. In my case it should be little endian (windows, intel, right?) which would mean that something like 01 10 as a 16 bit uinteger should be 2551 while in most programs dealing with memory it would be represented as 265.. no idea whats going on there.

I also learned that bits in a byte could be ordered as whatever and there seems to be no clear answer as to which bit is the actual first one since they could also be subject to bit-endianess and peoples definition about what is first differs. For me its left to right, for somebody else it might be what first appears when you add 1 to 0 or right to left.

Why does any of this matter? Well, curiosity mostly but I was also trying to write a class that would be able to extract X number of bits, starting from bit-address Y. I envisioned it sorta like .net string where i can go and type ".SubArray(12(position), 5(length))" then in case of data like in the top of this post it would retrieve "0001 0" or 2.

So could somebody clarifiy as to what is first and last in terms of bits and bytes in my environment, does it go right to left or left to right or both, wut? And why does this question exist in the first place, why couldn't the coding ancestors have agreed on something and stuck with it?

Comment: Modern processors only address bytes.  Addressing bits can be a dedicated processor instruction, nobody ever thought of making bit 0 anything else but the least significant bit.  For obvious reasons.

Comment: If you use bit-shifting operators, byte endianness does not matter at all. You can say `uint32_t x, y; y = (x << 12) & 1;` and then y would always store the 13th bit of x. Bit 0 will always be the LSB, and bit # `sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1` will always be the MSB.

Answer (score 6):

A shift is an *arithmetic* operation, not a memory-based operation: it is intended to work on the value, rather than on its representation. Shifting left by one is equivalent to a multiplication by two, and shifting right by one is equivalent to a division by two. *These* rules hold first, and if they conflict with the arrangement of the bits of a multibyte type in memory, then so much for the arrangement in memory. (Since shifts are the only way to examine bits within one byte, this is also why there is no meaningful notion of bit order within one byte.)

As long as you keep your operations to within a single data type (rather than byte-shifting long integers and them examining them as character sequences), the results will stay predictable. Examining the same chunk of memory through different integer types is, in this case, a bit like performing integer operations and then reading the bits as a float; there will be some change, but it's not the place of the integer arithmetic definitions to say exactly *what*. It's out of their scope.

Answer (score 2):

You have some understanding, but a couple misconceptions.

First off, arithmetic operations such as shifting are not concerned with the representation of the bits in memory, they are dealing with the value. Where memory representation comes into play is usually in distributed environments where you have cross-platform communication in the mix, where the data on one system is represented differently on another.

Your first comment...

> **I also learned that bits in a byte could be ordered as whatever and there seems to be no clear answer as to which bit is the actual first one since they could also be subject to bit-endianess and peoples definition about what is first differs**

This isn't entirely true, though the bits are only given meaning by the reader and the writer of data, generally bits within an 8-bit byte are always read from left (MSB) to right (LSB). The byte-order is what is determined by the endian-ness of the system architecture. It has to do with the representations of the data in memory, not the arithmetic operations.

Second...

> **And why does this question exist in the first place, why couldn't the coding ancestors have agreed on something and stuck with it?**

From Wikipedia:

> The initial endianness design choice was (is) mostly arbitrary, but later technology revisions and updates perpetuate the same endianness (and many other design attributes) to maintain backward compatibility. As examples, the Intel x86 processor represents a common little-endian architecture, and IBM z/Architecture mainframes are all big-endian processors. The designers of these two processor architectures fixed their endiannesses in the 1960s and 1970s with their initial product introductions to the market. Big-endian is the most common convention in data networking (including IPv6), hence its pseudo-synonym network byte order, and little-endian is popular (though not universal) among microprocessors in part due to Intel's significant historical influence on microprocessor designs. Mixed forms also exist, for instance the ordering of bytes within a 16-bit word may differ from the ordering of 16-bit words within a 32-bit word. Such cases are sometimes referred to as mixed-endian or middle-endian. There are also some bi-endian processors which can operate either in little-endian or big-endian mode.

Finally...

> **Why does any of this matter? Well, curiosity mostly but I was also trying to write a class that would be able to extract X number of bits, starting from bit-address Y. I envisioned it sorta like .net string where i can go and type ".SubArray(12(position), 5(length))" then in case of data like in the top of this post it would retrieve "0001 0" or 2.**

Many programming languages and libraries offer functions that allow you to convert to/from network (big endian) and host order (system dependent) so that you can ensure data you're dealing with is in the proper format, if you need to care about it. Since you're asking specifically about bit shifting, it doesn't matter in this case.

Read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/308274/what-determines-endianness) for more info